# SQL: DELETE,SELECT and LEFT JOIN - can I do that?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Basically I am trying to unfollow liked restaurant and get at the same time all followed restaurant without the one which has just been deleted and also select title from restaurant table all in one query.

I got this so far:

```sql
WITH deleted AS (DELETE from users_liked_restaurants WHERE users_liked_restaurants.user_id = 1 AND users_liked_restaurants.restaurant_id = 2 returning user_id)
SELECT restaurants.restaurant_id, restaurants.title FROM restaurants
LEFT JOIN users_liked_restaurants ON users_liked_restaurants.restaurant_id = restaurants.restaurant_id WHERE users_liked_restaurants.user_id = 1;
```

However this returns all liked restaurants by the user_id = 1 including the one I just deleted.

Comment: Why not do it in 2 statements within an explicit transaction? The SELECT has no reference to the 'deleted' CTE. To eliminate the deleted row from the result you must explicitly filter it out. The delete is not 'visible' since the CTE doesn't execute before the select, they are in the same execution scope.

Comment: Yes, you right, I can do: ```delete from users_liked_restaurants WHERE user_id = 1 AND restaurant_id = 2 returning *; SELECT restaurants.title FROM restaurants LEFT JOIN users_liked_restaurants ON users_liked_restaurants.restaurant_id = restaurants.restaurant_id WHERE users_liked_restaurants.user_id = 1;``` This works when I test the query in db, but I am using node with ```pg``` and this is treated as 2 statements - and got error: ```cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement```. I am getting close.

Comment: you can revert execution to ad-hoc mode by not supplying a name parameter to the query config object. https://node-postgres.com/features/queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that both parts of the query run inside the same statement, so one doesn't see the effects of the other.

Have the CTE return the `restaurant_id` of the deleted restaurant and exclude these restaurants from the query result:

```
WITH deleted AS (
  DELETE from users_liked_restaurants
  WHERE users_liked_restaurants.user_id = 1
    AND users_liked_restaurants.restaurant_id = 2
  RETURNING restaurant_id
)
SELECT restaurants.restaurant_id,
       restaurants.title
FROM restaurants
   LEFT JOIN users_liked_restaurants
      ON users_liked_restaurants.restaurant_id = restaurants.restaurant_id
WHERE users_liked_restaurants.user_id = 1
  AND NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1 FROM deleted
         WHERE deleted.restaurent_id = restaurants.restaurant_id
      );
```

Comment: Is the "not exists" really more efficient than a simple `<>` in this case?

Comment: It is at least as efficient as performing an outer join, because you can stop searching as soon as the first match is found.

Comment: Yes ... but you let the outer join with "users_liked_restaurant", ànd the outer join is not needed. So this one should work `WITH deleted AS (
  DELETE from users_liked_restaurants
  WHERE users_liked_restaurants.user_id = 1
    AND users_liked_restaurants.restaurant_id = 2
  RETURNING restaurant_id
)
SELECT restaurants.restaurant_id,
       restaurants.title
FROM restaurants
   INNER JOIN users_liked_restaurants
      ON users_liked_restaurants.restaurant_id = restaurants.restaurant_id
WHERE users_liked_restaurants.user_id = 1
 deleted.restaurant_id <> restaurants.restaurant_id

Comment: Apart from the missing `AND`, that will give you `missing FROM-clause entry for table "deleted"`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Laurenz for your solution! Worked perfectly. I also came out with similar solution:

```sql
WITH deleted AS (
DELETE from users_liked_restaurants WHERE users_liked_restaurants.user_id = 1 
AND users_liked_restaurants.restaurant_id = 2 returning restaurant_id)
SELECT restaurants.restaurant_id, restaurants.title 
FROM restaurants
LEFT JOIN users_liked_restaurants ON users_liked_restaurants.restaurant_id = restaurants.restaurant_id WHERE users_liked_restaurants.user_id = 1 
AND users_liked_restaurants.restaurant_id != 2;
```

Although I am gonna go with Laurenz solution! Thanks again!

Comment: That should cause an error, as `deleted` is not in the `FROM` list of the final `SELECT` statement.

Comment: yeah you right, I just edited to pass the value itself.

Comment: Now that looks fine and is probably faster than my solution.

Comment: oh really! but wasn't your solution safer with the ```NOT EXISTS``` ?

Comment: The result should be the same.